# asyncBlurFields not working in Redux-Form

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have some issue using asyncBlurFields in redux form, it just doesn't response,

**container:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import SupplierEditForm from '../../components/suppliers/SupplierEditForm' 
import { reduxForm, change } from 'redux-form'
import { createSupplierRequest, updateSupplierRequest, fetchSupplierInfoRequest, validateSupplierRequest } from '../../api/suppliers'
import { resetSupplierForm, supplierFormSubmitSuccess } from '../../actions/SuppliersActions'

class SuppliersEditView extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {isSubmitting: false}
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(resetSupplierForm())
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.params.supplier_id) {
                   this.props.dispatch(fetchSupplierInfoRequest(this.props.params.supplier_id))
        }

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.supplier.isAction==true) {
            if(!this.props.params.supplier_id) {
            this.context.router.push('/suppliers/edit/'+nextProps.supplier.supplier_id)

        } else {
            this.props.dispatch(fetchSupplierInfoRequest(nextProps.supplier.supplier_id))
        }
        this.setState({isSubmitting:true})
        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.hideStatus()
            this.props.dispatch(supplierFormSubmitSuccess())
        }, 1500)

    }



    }

    hideStatus() {
        this.setState({isSubmitting:false})
    }

    render() {

        let pageHeader 

        if(this.props.fields.company_name.value) {
            pageHeader =  <h1 className="page-header">Suppliers - { this.props.fields.company_name.value }</h1>
        }
        else {
            pageHeader =  <h1 className="page-header">Suppliers</h1>
        }

          return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                {pageHeader}
                <SupplierEditForm 
                fields={this.props.fields} 
                handleSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} 
                dispatchSupplier={this.props.dispatchSupplier.bind(this)} 
                supplier={this.props.supplier.payload} 
                isSubmitting={this.state.isSubmitting} 
                dispatchFieldChange={this.props.dispatchFieldChange}
                supplier_id={this.props.params.supplier_id}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const validateSupplier = (values, dispatch) => {
    console.log('hi')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dispatch(validateSupplierRequest(values))
        .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        });
    })
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    supplier: state.suppliers.supplierInfo,
    initialValues: state.suppliers.supplierInfo.payload

})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
    dispatchSupplier: (values) => {
        !props.params.supplier_id ? dispatch(createSupplierRequest(values)) :     dispatch(updateSupplierRequest(values, props.params.supplier_id))

    },
    dispatchFieldChange: (field, value) => {
        dispatch(change('SupplierEditForm',field,value))
    }
})

SuppliersEditView.propTypes = {
    asyncValidating: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    resetForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

SuppliersEditView.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}

SuppliersEditView = reduxForm({
    form: 'SupplierEditForm',
    fields: ['company_logo','company_name', 'business_registration_no', 'mailing_address', 'billing_address', 'phone', 'email', 'fax', 'contact_person', 'contact_phone', 'contact_email', 'comments'],
    asyncValidate: validateSupplier,
    asyncBlurFields:['business_registration_no']
})(SuppliersEditView)



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SuppliersEditView)
```

**component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import ReactDOM, { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import { config } from '../../config'
import _ from 'lodash'

class SupplierEditForm extends Component {
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
        file: null,
        imagePreviewUrl: null
    }
}




handleImageChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            file: file,
            imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
        })
    }
    this.props.dispatchFieldChange(['company_logo'],file)

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}

triggerImageUpload() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.upload).click()
}


render () {

    const { fields: { company_logo, company_name, business_registration_no, mailing_address, billing_address, phone, email, fax, contact_person, contact_phone, contact_email, comments }, handleSubmit, isSubmitting } = this.props

    let imageSection 

    if(this.state.imagePreviewUrl) {
        imageSection = <img src={this.state.imagePreviewUrl} width="100" onClick={this.triggerImageUpload.bind(this)}/>
    } else if (_.isEmpty(this.props.supplier) || _.isNull(this.props.supplier.filename)){
        imageSection = <div className="img-placeholder" onClick={this.triggerImageUpload.bind(this)}></div>
    } else if (!_.isNull(this.props.supplier.filename) || !_.isEmpty(this.props.supplier)){
        imageSection = <img src={config.FILE_DIR + this.props.supplier.filename} width="100"  onClick={this.triggerImageUpload.bind(this)}/>
    } 


    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.dispatchSupplier)} >
            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting} className="btn btn-primary mr8">
                {
                    isSubmitting == true ?
                        <i className="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
                    :
                        'Save'
                }
            </button>
            <Link to="/suppliers" className="btn btn-secondary">Back</Link>
            <div className="row">
                {
                    isSubmitting ? 
                        <div className="form-overlay"/>
                    : null
                }
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="mb24">Supplier details</h2>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Company logo</label>
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            {imageSection}
                        </div>
                        <input type="file" ref="upload" className="col-xs-12 mb24 hide" {...company_logo} value={null} onChange={this.handleImageChange.bind(this)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Company name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...company_name} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Business registration no.</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...business_registration_no} required/> 


                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Mailing address</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...mailing_address} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Billing address</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...billing_address} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Comments</label>
                        <textarea type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...comments} required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2 className="mb24">Contact details</h2>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...phone} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Fax</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...fax} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" className="col-xs-12"  {...email} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Contact person</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...contact_person} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Contact phone</label>
                        <input type="text" className="col-xs-12"  {...contact_phone} required/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Contact email</label>
                        <input type="email" className="col-xs-12"  {...contact_email} required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}


}



export default SupplierEditForm
```

However, whenever form is submitted, business_registration_no is suppose to respond on input lost focus, but it does not respond, have been trying for whole day. The weird thing is instead of firing this.props.dispatchSupplier when handleSubmit is invoked, it fires asyncValidate. Is there anything wrong in my code? Desperate for help!!

Comment: I believe you need to use `Field` component of redux form instead of HTML default `input`s. As from the docs - `<Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text"/>` (docs example - http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/docs/GettingStarted.md/)

Answer (score 0):

yep. need to use the `Field`-component and then also pass `onBlur` to that component..
like so :

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1834
or so:

```
render() {
const { input: { value, onChange, onBlur }, meta: { touched, error } } = this.props
return (
    <div>
        <div className="example-class">
            <input 
                type="tel" 
                className={this.inputFormClass(touched, error)} 
                autoComplete="on" 
                onChange={this.setPhoneNumber.bind(this)} 
                placeholder="some Placeholder" 
                onBlur={() => onBlur(value)}
            />
        </div>
        {this.showErrorMessage(touched, error)}
    </div>
)
```

}